# Detect if user opens OS X notification center with javascript

Tags: javascript, macos

Is it possible to detect if the user opens OS X notification center with javascript? I.e. visibilitychange and $(window).blur() does not detect it.

I would like to temporarily lock an online exam if a pupil is using the calculator or any social function (twitter, messager etc) in the OS X notification center.

Answer (score 0):

You might experiment with sending a notification to the notification center, and then use the event handler onshow.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012932-SW1

Comment: Thanks, well worth a try. Unfortunately the notification.onshow fires directly (when the notification is displayed in an alert modal). So it does not work for this purpose.